# VLOOKUP returning offset values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, index-match

I have setup VLOOKUPS before but for some reason this one isn't functioning correctly.
WORKSHEET1 -

[image: Worksheet1]

WORKSHEET2 -

[image]

If I change FALSE to TRUE I get an aproximate value of B2, 1525 Oak St. I saw similar questions that looked like maybe people were using a simplier method to return a value when you'll always know what the index of the column in the lookup table but couldn't determine what that would be...or why this vlookup isn't working because it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: A quick and dirty fix is to switch your B and C columns around in Worksheet 2. I.e Row1 would be JP, Madison, 17316 Elm street. You formula will work then :)

Comment: =VLOOKUP(M2,CHOOSE({1,2},O5:O6,N5:N6),2,0) This formula will give you the output but just change according with your sheet.I look at madison in m2 and i use choose because the return value is in the left side o5:o6 is the cells where i have the city including madison and n5:n6 is the return value in your case address.
Hope it helps

Comment: Vlookup is janky when it comes to things like this. `Index(Match())` is better, though not quite as easy to remember the necessary syntax